# ADF Understanding the Case Statement

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-synapse

Given the following Derived column Expression

```
case(Rolling =='A'||Rolling == 'B'||Rolling == 'C'|| Rolling =="S"
     , "
     , case(Alpha== 'EE'
         , toString(toDate(Manu_Date, 'yyyy-MM-dd'))
         , case(Alpha=='CW', Del_Date,"))
)
```

2 questions

1. Is there a Better way to write this code?
2. What is this code trying to do ?

I am trying to understand what they are trying to achieve with this expression?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- In the given expression, after Rolling=="S", it is not double Quotes `"`. It should be two single quotes`''`
- Similarly, after Del_date, also it should be two single Quotes.

```scala
case(Rolling =='A'||Rolling ==  'B'||Rolling ==  'C'|| Rolling =="S", '',
case(Alpha==  'EE', toString(toDate(Manu_Date, 'yyyy-MM-dd')),
case(Alpha=='CW', Del_Date,'' )))
```

> 1. What is this code trying to do ?

- Syntax for case statement is
  `case(condition,true_expression,false_expression)`
- Initially, this expression checks if Rolling is 'A' or 'B' or 'C' or 'S' and then assign the value as `''` (empty string) for the derived column.
- When the above condition is false, then checks if Alpha is 'EE' and assign the value of **Manu_Date** in string format.
- When the second condition also fails, it checks if Alpha='CW' and assign the value of **Del_Date** column.
- When all the above conditions are not met, `''` (empty string) is assigned. This will be the default value.
- I repro'd this with sample input.
  [image]
  img1: input data
- In derived column transformation, new column is added, and the expression is given as in below script.

```scala
case(Rolling =='A'||Rolling ==  'B'||Rolling ==  'C'|| Rolling =="S", '',
case(Alpha==  'EE', toString(toDate(Manu_Date, 'yyyy-MM-dd')),
case(Alpha=='CW', Del_Date,'' )))
```

[image]
img2: Derived column transformation output

> 2. Is there a Better way to write this code?

- Since the order of condition is important to assign the values to the new column, case statement is better way to do.
- But, instead of using nested case statements, we can use single case statement to achieve the same.
  Syntax:
   `case( condition_1, expression_1, condition_2, expression_2,.......... condition_n,expression_n,default_expression)`.
  Null will be the default value, when the default expression is omitted.

**Modified expression**

```scala
case(Rolling =='A'||Rolling ==  'B'||Rolling ==  'C'|| Rolling =="S", '',
Alpha==  'EE', toString(toDate(Manu_Date, 'yyyy-MM-dd')),
Alpha=='CW', Del_Date,'' )
```

[image]
img 3:  Results of both case statements

Both the expressions are added in the derived column transformation and results are same in both cases.